# Can deflate/gzip be with "deny from all"?

Tags: .htaccess

I am kind of confused with the .htaccess file. I want gzip compression and deny from all in a directory. My question is can "deny from all" be with gzip compression or it has any problems?

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

deny from all
```

Comment: @JohnFlatness I do not know. I believe only what I see and hear.

Comment: @JohnFlatness - Your comment doesn't make any sense in the context of the question.

Comment: @JohnFlatness - Then say *that*.

Comment: @JohnFlatness I think I am in a Q&A site. Not a Q&Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deny from all` means no one can access the directory directly via a URL. Any content sent to the browser from that directory has to come via a server-side script placed elsewhere, which means that .htaccess is bypassed entirely - so the compression won't take place.

Your server-side script will therefore have to perform the compression on its own using [`http_deflate`](http://php.net/http_deflate) before outputting the data from those files.

Comment: In this directory I have a XML file that is "compressed" before output. I checked it and it was correctly compressed. So I added the "deny from all". To clear my mind,you mean that the compression will not be made?

Comment: @fiogkos - Why did you add that directive (`deny from all`)? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: @fiogkos: `deny from all` prevents you from accessing that XML file via your browser; therefore, your webserver will never compress it (because as far as it is concerned, there won't *be* anything to compress - it will never try to send the file). .htaccess files don't apply in other circumstances; only when trying to access a resource directly from the client. Liked Jared, I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, but this isn't going to do that.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Ok that cleared things uo. I wanted to "hide" this XML file from anyone who search for it and also to have a compression. So  I have to remove `deny from all` for the compression to happen.